# Problems with display name/sort name saving as contact.first_name

Tags: contacts

Every time a contact record is edited and then saved, the display name and sort name revert to "contact.first_name [Last name]". When you are in edit mode, the First name is still there (and other associated fields, such as email greeting all still display the contact's first name).

I've updated CiviCRM to 4.7.18 - tis hasn't fixed anything. (This site has lots of events and I saw a couple of people reporting issues with events on the latest version so avoided 4.7.19).

I can save it using the phpMyAdmin UI but that's only temporary, until a user edits the same contact record again.

Drupal 7.54

Comment: Hi Rose, the format of the display name and the sort name are configured at _Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences_. What is shown there?

Comment: @Kainuk you are a genius! The first curly bracket was missing for both (Most likely caused by user error by a new user exploring the admin settings?)

Comment: Okay, I will combine these two in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the display name and the sort name are configured at *Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences*.  Check if this format is correct. (For example, the curly brackets must match).